# Verb "sehen" to use with possessive adjective

Tags: usage, declension

I am beginner in learning German and I am a bit confused. When I try to translate English sentence: "I see her nephew now." to German, both Google and DeepL translates as "Ich sehe jetzt ihren Neffen."

Here I ask, why "Neffe" takes "-n", it is not plural, doesn't it have to be "...ihren Neffe." in akkusativ??

Comment: This does not have anything to do with the verb *sehen* specifically or the possessive. The reason is that *Neffe* is a weak noun, so it takes the form *Neffen* in all cases except nominative singular. See https://www.verbformen.de/deklination/substantive/Neffe.htm

Comment: For reference, this is part of the N-Declension concept in German. https://deutsch.lingolia.com/en/grammar/nouns/declension/n-declension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here I ask, why "Neffe" takes "-n", it is not plural, doesn't it have to be "...ihren Neffe." in akkusativ??

First off, your assumption that it is *Akkusativ* is correct. "ihren" is a so-called *Possessivpronomen*, in English "her" (from "her nephew"). These are treated similar to *Adjektive* in respect of getting declinated *with* the *Nomen* (noun) they go with:

> mein Auto (Nominativ Singular)
> mein**es** Auto**s** (Genitiv Singular)
> mein**em** Auto (Dativ Singular)
> mein Auto (Akkusativ Singular)

The forms are different for *Maskulinum*, *Femininum* and *Neutrum*, the above ("das Auto") is a *Neutrum*. "Neffe" is a *Maskulinum* and hence:

> ihr Neffe (Nominativ Singular)
> ihr**es** Neffe**n** (Genitiv Singular)
> ihr**em** Neffe**n** (Dativ Singular)
> ihr**en** Neffe**n** (Akkusativ Singular)

There are different declensions for nouns in German, but there is one rule which has no exceptions: if an *Adjektiv*, *Numeral*, *Demonstrativpronomen* or *Possessivpronomen* goes with a *Nomen* then both are declinated the same way (same *Kasus*, same *Numerus*).

Here is an example for that:

> ein leuchtendes rotes Auto
> ein leuchtend rotes Auto

In the first case there are two *Adjektiva* ("leuchtend", "rot"), which both go with the *Nomen* ("Auto"). So the car is "red" as well as "shining". Both *Adjektiva* are declinated along with "Auto".

In the second case, "leuchtend" is not declinated. This is because it is not a property of the *car* any more, but a property of its *colour* - "red". "Leuchtend" is not even an *Adjektiv* any more but an "*Adverb*". The two expressions mean "a shining red car" (1) and "a shiningly red car" (2).

Answer (score 1):

For each German noun, you have to remember the definite nominative singular article and the plural. I think you already do that.

- das Haus, Häuser
- die Maus, Mäuse

For the masculine nouns, you have to remember the genitive singular on top, as there are three declination classes for those:

- der Zug, des Zuges, Züge

That's the strong declination which behaves as you expected.

- der Neffe, des Neffen, Neffen
- der Gedanke, des Gedankens, Gedanken

Those are the two flavours of the weak (or n-) declination. They have an *(-e)n* ending in all cases but nominative singular and the genitive singular is irregular either -en, on -ens. You can spot the weak declination from that irregular genitive singular ending. That's why you have to drill it.

Note there are also nouns made from adjectives and adjective-like words as e.g. der/die/das Auszubildende which follow *adjective* declination.

And there's *das Herz* which is completely irregular.

Answer (score 1):

That's called n-deklination in German. All the masculine names who are ended at -e like Neffe, some animal names like der Löwe, der Hase, der Falke, der Affe, der Bulle, der Rabe, der Schimpanse

Für folgende Nomen gilt die N-Deklination:

## Nomen mit der Endung „-e“, z. B.:

Personen, z. B.: der Kollege, der Junge, der Kunde, der Experte, der Neffe, der Riese, der Zeuge, der Sklave, der Bote, der Erbe, der Gatte
Nationalitäten, z. B.: der Pole, der Russe, der Grieche, der Franzose, der Brite, der Chinese, der Türke
Tiere, z. B.: der Löwe, der Hase, der Falke, der Affe, der Bulle, der Rabe, der Schimpanse

## Nomen mit der Endung „-oge”, „-ent”, „-ant”, „-at”, „-ist” (meist Bezeichnungen von Berufen oder Personen), z. B.:

- der Biologe, der Psychologe, der Gynäkologe, der Pädagoge, der Soziologe
- der Student, der Dozent, der Produzent, der Präsident, der Patient, der Absolvent, der Assistent
- der Lieferant, der Praktikant, der Elefant, der Diamant, der Emigrant, der Musikant
- der Soldat, der Kandidat, der Diplomat, der Automat
- der Tourist, der Polizist, der Journalist, der Spezialist, der Terrorist

## andere Nomen, z. B.:

der Katholik, der Fotograf, der Planet, der Architekt, der Herr, der Mensch, der Nachbar, der Bauer, der Held, der Bär, der Prinz, der Idiot

source= https://deutsch-mit-anna.de/lektion/n-deklination/
these all will get a n when they're conjugated